# Function asymptotes

Tags: calculus, functions

Consider $ f (x) = \frac {x ^ 4} {4} - 2x ^ 3 + 9 \frac {x ^ 2} {2}, x \in \mathbb {R} $

a) Find the asymptotes (vertical and horizontal) on the $ f $ chart, if any. If not there. Justify

b) Study growth and find local extremes of $ f $

c) Study the concavity and find the inflection points of $ f $

d) Calculate the intersections of the $ f $ chart with the $ x $ and $ y $ axes, if any. Sketch the $ f $ graph.

Can anyone give me any tips or show me the way to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Since the function $f$ is a polynomial function, its graph has no asymptotes.

b) We start by compute the derivative
$$
f'(x)=x^3-6x^2+9x=x(x-3)^2
$$
Hence $f(x)=0$ for $x=0,3$.

However

$f'(x)>0$ for $0<x<3$ and $x>3$,

while

$f'(x)<0$ for $x<0$.

Hence $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and increasing on  $(0,3)\cup(3,\infty)$. Inparticular, $f$ has an absolute minimum at $x=0$.

c) Since
$$
f''(x)=3x^2-12x+9=3(x^2-6x+3)
$$
we have $f''(x)=0$ for 
$$
x=3\pm\sqrt{6}
$$
we have

$f''(x)>0$  for $x<3-\sqrt{6}$ and $x>3+\sqrt{6}$ 
and $f''(x)<0$ for $3-\sqrt{6}<x<3+\sqrt{6}$.

It follows that $f$ is concave up on $(-\infty,3-\sqrt{6})\cup(3+\sqrt{6},\infty)$ and concave  down on $(3-\sqrt{6},3+\sqrt{6})$.

d) Since $f(0)=0$ is an absolute minimum, there is no other $x$-intercept. Hence the $x$ and $y$-intercept is $(0,0)$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) $f(x)$ is a polynomial; polynomials have no horizontal or vertical asymptotes.

b) Use calculus to find extrema and study growth on intervals between extrema using the first derivative (there should be 3 critical points).

c) Use calculus again; recall that the second derivative contains information about the concavity of $f(x)$

d) $f(x)$ intersects the x-axis when $f(x) = 0$. Just find the zeroes (notice that you can factor out an $x^{2}$) To find where $f(x)$ intersects the y-axis, evaluate $f(0)$. There should only be one answer to this since $f(x)$ is a function.